# Appengine REST library - Python and Django

Tags: python, django, web-services, google-app-engine, rest

I want to provide a REST API for my Django application which will run on Google App engine. I stumbled upon [appengine-rest-server](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/) and found to be useful. But i would like to get some real world usage examples if any, and any gotchas. Is there any better alternatives to consider?

Comment: can [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) or [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) not be used on GAE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using django-nonrel with tastypie.  I needed to make a couple of small code changes at the time, but I think the latest versions in the repos work together.

http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/12076483835/tastypie-on-django-nonrel-on-app-engine

Because of the lack of many-to-many relations, I've been using ListProperties, and they seem to work fine with tastypie.

tastypie APIs are designed to match models.  If your API will be creating/getting/updating/deleting instances of your models, tastypie will require less code.

django-piston is very popular too, but I haven't tried it on app engine.

Comment: I tried doing this recently and the issue is resolved but some other dependencies missing. That could be simply solved by copy modules to given location.

Answer (score 2):

I think that currently the best option for writing a REST API is django-piston https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston, and I think that it should work perfectly with Google AppEngine, although I never tried it.

Comment: i tried it, you just have to fix some imports in the piston modules (at least when you dont include the library in the root path of your app) and then it works quite well

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
i recommend to take a look on: [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) which turned out to work even nicer than [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) it helps you also with things like versioning your API and mamange multiple endpoints nicly

Answer (score 0):

I've used restlet on app engine without any issues. http://www.restlet.org/

I stopped using it in favor of just using basic HttpServlet for posts and gets of json data.

Comment: he's running django (Python) ^^

Answer (score 0):

Currently, appengine-rest-server doesn't support ndb models.